# Vertical lines with CSS

Tags: css, background, line, vertical-alignment

I have a `#comments` element which contains `.comment` elements. I would like to have 5 vertical lines from left to right, each 1px in width, 100% height (till the end of the `#comments` element), with 20px between them and without images. I tried to do that myself, but my CSS-fu isn't that high. Any help would be much appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="comments">
    <div class="comment level1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="comment level2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="comment level3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#comments {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.comment {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.level1 {}
.level2 { margin-left: 20px; }
.level3 { margin-left: 40px; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tuZB6/1/).

Here's how I imagine it:

```
|[comment      ]
|  |[comment   ]
|  |[comment   ]
|  |  |[comment]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some reason you need to have all the divs as direct children of the outer parent div? If you nest the divs you can accomplish this very easily:

css:

```
div div {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

nested html

```
<div id="comments">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <br/>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            <br/>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                <br/>
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                   <br/>
                   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

updated fiddle showing how it would look here nested down to 5 levels:

http://jsfiddle.net/webchemist/tuZB6/4/

Comment: This don't work for me because in actual design I have margin between `.comment` elements, but this solution don't draw vertical lines in those gaps.

Comment: This is the best I can get w/ border for `.comment` element. http://i.imgur.com/Qy1qW.png

Comment: Ohh, just got how you have structured elements... it might just work! Thanks! :)